# How to set iptables rule - access to only one ip/domain

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I need help with create iptabes rule, that user's ip (specified in local eth) can connect only with definied ethernet ip address/domain and all other traffic should be dropped.
Should works only one website.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s <localip> -d <allowed ip> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <localip> -j DROP
```

also

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

to check rule performance.

```
[ USER ] -> [ SERVER (filtering in FORWARD) ] -> (internet) + allowed ip
```

One more also. To be able to filter domain names you need Level 7 filtering, which is better done with proxy or mikrotik router :) 
Of course there are some tricks like getting dns name resolved while applying filters, but some of modern websites have several ip addresses which could change time to time.

For example yahoo:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.137.246.7
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 72.30.35.10
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 72.30.35.9
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.137.246.8
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.138.219.231
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 98.138.219.232
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 2001:4998:44:41d::4
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 2001:4998:c:1023::5
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 2001:4998:c:1023::4
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 2001:4998:58:1836::11
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 2001:4998:58:1836::10
Name:   yahoo.com
Address: 2001:4998:44:41d::3
```

Comment: I adding rules on main server. Debian.

Comment: Do you already have forwarding? I mean `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is `1` or `0`?

Comment: My switches haven't active level 7 layer. Btw I can't easy catch torrent users by that. Just old switches.

Comment: In /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward it's 1

Comment: Great, then just add two above rules for IP you want to restrict.
Alternatively, you can set `iptables -P FORWARD DROP`, so ANY connections that are not explicitly allowed will be dropped.

Comment: Is it possible insert that mnemonic name instead of IP?

Comment: no, iptables doesn't have built in resolver. For that purpose better use transparent proxy.

Comment: Actually user can't visit this website.
I used first and second iptables rule.

Comment: Ping goes fine?

Comment: Ping is disabled for all users. I ping domain to resolve ip and use this

Comment: Then you should try `telnet <target ip> 80` form user PC. If it connects, then forwarding works. Other way there could be problem in name resolving.

Comment: Ok, it's should be fine. My other script blocking all traffic for user. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.